# Find out if DatagridView Cell is Clicked

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have 2 grids on a form.

Both grids are binded to object Panel and PanelLines.

If user click first panel grid, the second panel line grid will show the related panel lines.

If the user clicks the panel grid on the same cell again, I want panel line grid to scroll rows as such visible rows hide and bottom rows show up.

The following code does the scrolling part.

dgvPanelItem.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgvPanelItem.DisplayedRowCount(False) - 1

But I need help in finding out, if first grid ( panel grid ) is already clicked or not.

Answer (score 0):

Put a static variable flag, this should solve the specified problem